# I have a problem in react app using react router dom and have pages routes like authaPage,

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

React Hook "useState" is called in function "authPage" which is neither a React function component or a custom React Hook function  react-hooks/rules-of-hooks.
This error is shown while using useState hook in authPage Route component

Comment: where's the code, mate?

Answer (score 0):

```
app.js file

import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
import AuthPage from './Pages/authPage'
import EventPage from './Pages/eventPage'
import BookingPage from './Pages/bookingPage';
import MainNavigator from './component/MainNavigator';

function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <React.Fragment>
        <MainNavigator />
        <Switch>
          <Redirect from="/" to="/auth" exact />
          <Route path="/auth" component={AuthPage} />
          <Route path="/events" component={EventPage} />
          <Route path="/bookings" component={BookingPage} />
        </Switch>
      </React.Fragment>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}

export default App;

authpage.js file

import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Grid, TextField, Icon, Button } from '@material-ui/core';

import '../App.css';


const authPage = (props) => {
    const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
    return (
        <Grid container className='container_auth'>
            <Grid item lg={6} sm={6} xs={12} className='container_auth_form1'>
                <div className="firstGrid">
                    <h1>authPage</h1>
                </div>
            </Grid>
            <Grid item lg={6} sm={6} xs={12} className='container_auth_form2'>
            <form onSubmit={onSubmitLogin} className='subcont_auth' noValidate autoComplete="off">
                <TextField fullWidth error={error} id="standard-error" label="Email" value={email} onChange={(text) => setEmail(text.target.value)} /><br /><br />
                <TextField fullWidth error={error} helperText={error ? "incorrect password" : ''} id="standard-error" label="Password" value={password} onChange={(text) => setPassword(text.target.value)} />
                <Button
                    variant="contained"
                    color="primary"
                    style={{ marginTop: '2rem' }}
                    endIcon={<Icon>send</Icon>}
                    fullWidth
                    size='large'

                    >
                    Login
      </Button>
            </form>
        </Grid>
        </Grid >
    )
}

export default authPage
```